# vba vlookup/error handling - type mismatch error

Tags: vba, error-handling, vlookup

im getting a `run time error 13 - type mismatch error`

any ideas?

```
outputCell = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A" & row & ",'Current Defects'!$A$" & 2 & ":$B$" & 1000 & ",2,FALSE))," - ", (=VLOOKUP(A" & row & ",'Current Defects'!$A$" & 2 & ":$B$" & 1000 & ",2,FALSE))"
```

Comment: It helps if you provide the minimum amount of code in order for someone else to replicate the error. How are your variables dimensioned? What is the value of `row` at runtime?  Can you show more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `(=` before the second `VLOOKUP`.

You also did not properly escape doublequotes in the `IsNA` function.

On a single line, try:

```
outputCell = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A" & row & ",'Current Defects'!$A$" & 2 & ":$B$" & 1000 & ",2,FALSE)),"" - "", VLOOKUP(A" & row & ",'Current Defects'!$A$" & 2 & ":$B$" & 1000 & ",2,FALSE))"
```

For legibility, split it among multiple lines:

```
outputCell = "=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A" _
                  & row & ",'Current Defects'!$A$" & 2 & ":$B$" & 1000 & ",2,FALSE))," _
                  & """ - "", VLOOKUP(A" & row & ",'Current Defects'!$A$" & 2 & ":$B$" _
                  & 1000 & ",2,FALSE))"
```

Comment: thank you David. I would show more of the code but the variable names are fairly sensitive to the organisation. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome! If this solves the problem, do consider marking this answer as "Accepted" :)

Answer (score 0):

In a string in VBA you need to escape double quotes by, well, doubling them.
So if you want a string containing `Hello "bob" how are you?` You would write `"Hello ""bob"" how are you?"`

In your code:

```
"=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A" & row & ",'Current Defects'!$A$" & 2 & ":$B$" & 1000 & ",2,FALSE))," - ", (=VLOOKUP(A" & row & ",'Current Defects'!$A$" & 2 & ":$B$" & 1000 & ",2,FALSE))"
```

It's getting confused because of the `," - ",` part. You are trying to subtract strings, which cannot be done.

Furthermore, your formula does not make sense. I would recommend testing it in an Excel cell first, then carefully modifying it, inserting your variables in VBA...

Comment: thank you. I previously tested the function within excel and it worked fine. I was getting errors back once I added the error handling functionality in vba, i assumed it was a misplaced quote as you have mentioned not ending it properly.